# How to use two joins on a sql query? Syntax

Tags: sql, database

Sorry asking such a newbie question but I've been trying to understand this SQL query and add a thing and i can't make it happen.

Here is the query:

```
select 
    p.id, p.nick, p.creation_date 
from 
    tb_player p 
left outer join 
    tb_invoice i on (i.player_id = p.id), tb_player_last_login tpl
where 
    p.creation_date < now() - '12 months'::interval 
    and tpl.last_login_date < now() - '12 months'::interval 
    and tpl.player_id = p.id
    and p.id > 9999
    and (p.email = 'EDITE-SEU-EMAIL' or p.email = 'configure-seu-email')
    and i.id is null
limit 15000;
```

So I'm selecting a group of people from this `tb_player` and I have another table called `tb_email_list` and I need to say somewhere to include the players of `tb_player` that have the same email of `tb_email_list` that are valid.

- `tb_player` has nick and email camp
- `tb_email_list` player_id, email, is_valid

I tried to put some joins but nothing I do seems to work...

A little help please?

My friend helped me and it goes like

```
select p.id, p.nick, p.creation_date 
from tb_player_last_login tpl, tb_player p 
left outer join tb_invoice i on (i.player_id = p.id)
left join tb_email_list e on e.player_id = p.id
where p.creation_date < now() - '12 months'::interval 
and tpl.last_login_date < now() - '12 months'::interval 
and tpl.player_id = p.id
and p.id > 9999
and (p.email = 'EDITE-SEU-EMAIL' or p.email = 'configure-seu-email' or e.is_valid = -1)
and i.id is null
limit 15000
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You shouldn't suddenly mix the *proper* ANSI JOIN's (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) with the old, deprecated *comma-separated list of tables* style of JOINs - use **one** style (preferably the one with the **explicit** JOIN keywords!) and stick to it! There should be a `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` before your `tb_player_last_login` in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another join like this:

```
select 
    p.id, p.nick, p.creation_date 
from 
    tb_player p 
inner join tb_player_last_login tpl on tpl.player_id = p.id
left outer join tb_invoice i on i.player_id = p.id 
left outer join tb_email_list l on p.id = l.player_id
where 
    p.creation_date < now() - '12 months'::interval 
    and tpl.last_login_date < now() - '12 months'::interval 
    and p.id > 9999
    and i.id is null
    and (p.email = 'EDITE-SEU-EMAIL' or p.email = 'configure-seu-email')
limit 15000;
```

Note, I also added a third join to `tb_player_last_login` to ensure consistency - you shouldn't really mix old-style and new-style ANSI join syntax, it will work, but it makes the query much harder to read.

Comment: In the new left join it says that "There is an entry for table "p", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query." on the p.id = l.lplayer_id

Answer (score 2):

You just add another `join` clause:

```
select p.id, p.nick, p.creation_date 
from tb_player p 
left outer join tb_invoice i on i.player_id = p.id
left outer join tb_player_last_login tpl on tpl.player_id = p.id --here
where p.creation_date < now() - '12 months'::interval 
and tpl.last_login_date < now() - '12 months'::interval 
and p.id > 9999
and (p.email = 'EDITE-SEU-EMAIL' or p.email = 'configure-seu-email')
and i.id is null
limit 15000;
```